# Regex to grab first and last number on each line

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm stuck here...

So, I have a string:

6,5,1,0,0,4,0,2,1121,18,54,67,6,0
15,5,10,0,6,5,1,3,20,47,119,153,15,0
187,72,115,2,8,19,37,121,74,98,511,622,143,44

I need to get the first and last number of each row and put them into the table (with JavaScript).

As a result I need

```
<tr><td>6</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>15</td><td>0</td></tr>
<tr><td>187</td><td>44</td></tr>
```

Any help is appreciated. Maybe even a hint :)

Comment: `str.match(/^(\d+).*(\d+)$/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a regex for this problem but [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) instead, then do something like this.

HTML

```
<table id="results"></table>
```

Javascript

```
var table = document.getElementById("results"),
    strings = "6,5,1,0,0,4,0,2,1121,18,54,67,6,0\n15,5,10,0,6,5,1,3,20,47,119,153,15,0\n187,72,115,2,8,19,37,121,74,98,511,622,143,44".split("\n");

strings.forEach(function (string) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr"),
        tdFirst = document.createElement("td"),
        tdLast = document.createElement("td"),
        array = string.split(",");

    tdFirst.textContent = array[0];
    tdLast.textContent = array[array.length - 1];

    tr.appendChild(tdFirst);
    tr.appendChild(tdLast);
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/VRFBL/)

Comment: I've chosen this way. Works as it should! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regexp

`/^([0-9]+),[0-9,]+,([0-9]+)$/`

Will give you a match for the first and last number

Answer (score 0):

You can split the multiline string into lines with

```
x = "a\nb\nc"
lines = x.split("\n")
```

Loop through each line and use regexp to find the first and last digit.
One easy to understand way is to use a separate one for the first and last.

```
var first = line.match(/^\d+/)[0]
var last = line.match(/\d+$/)[0]
```

Regexp isn't really necessary though, you could just use .split(',').

To make the table, I would suggest using jQuery and reading the jQuery docs for .append or google for something like "how to make table with jquery".

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Test()
{
  var stringValue = "6,5,1,0,0,4,0,2,1121,18,54,67,6,0";
  stringValue = BuildRow(stringValue);  //stringValue = <tr><td>6</td><td>0</td></tr>
  alert(stringValue);
}

//Build a table row from string
function BuildRow(sValue)
{
   var first = GetFirstNumberOfLine(sValue);
   var last = GetLastNumberOfLine(sValue);
   var row = "<tr><td>" + first + "</td><td>" + last +  "</td></tr>";
   return row;
}

//Return The first number of a string
function GetFirstNumberOfLine(sValue)
{
     var numberArray = sValue.split(",");
     return  numberArray[0];
}

//Return The first last number of a string
function GetLastNumberOfLine(sValue)
{
     var numberArray = sValue.split(",");
     return numberArray[numberArray.length -1 ];
}
</script>
```